# Strange characters on CiviCRM dashboard

Tags: dashboard

CiviCRM 4.4.7 on Pantheon (CiviCRM starter kit).

When I go to the dashboard page, I see strange characters that look like white checkmarks in a circle with a green background.

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: do a menu rebuild, clear cache for CMS and check

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the css of your theme clashes with the css of civi (there is a style rule to avoid repeating that icon, that might be overwrited by one in your theme).

As a quick test, can you switch to the default drupal theme and see if it's still an issue?

If not, you will need to modify your theme to add a rule so the background image for the icons doesn't repeat. Not complicated, but likely specific to your theme, so hard to give you a generic advice without knowing the specifics